# Значение тега

Tags: html

Нашел на неком сайте такую конструкцию, скажите, что она значит ?

```
content: ".";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

видимо имеется в виду данный хак

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

т.е. это один из вариантов clearfix т.е. приема, который раздвигает границы контейнера "плавающего" (float) элемента

Answer (score 0):

[content](http://htmlbook.ru/css/content)

> Свойство content позволяет вставлять генерируемое содержание в текст веб-страницы, которое первоначально в тексте отсутствует. Применяется совместно с псевдоэлементами :after и :before, они соответственно указывают отображать новое содержимое после или до элемента, к которому добавляются.

Comment: А что делает именно найденный мною код, именно что значит точка ?